# Potential form vs Intransitive Verbs

Tags: potential-form, transitivity

So I was looking at conjugations and I saw that the potential form of **切る【きる】** is **切れる【きれる】**. However, 切れる【きれる】 is also an intransitive verb. There are others e.g.

- 休む【やすむ】＞休める【やすめる】
- 行く【いく】＞行ける【いける】

So, what's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Verbs like 切れる can have two meanings, the potential one or the intransitive one. You determine by context.

```
上司が切れた
```

In this case, it is clear the boss got mad. It could also be written as キレた.

```
この紐、切れる？
```

Here, it should be clear the person is asking "Can this string be cut?". This meaning can also be written as 〜切ることができる.